# JSF / CSS Attribute Selector

Tags: css, jsf, css-selectors

I have a table with two columns. I would like to style the value of the second column differently using CSS when it contains a specific value.

Here's the view:

```xml
<h:dataTable id="tb_USER_DETAILS" border="1" var="userDtls"
    value="#{freqViewTable.freqDtlsTable}" columnClasses="keydata, occupieddata"
    style="width: 250px" styleClass="overalltable">
    <h:column id="frequency">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Frequency (Hz)" style="font-size:12pt" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{userDtls.keyFrequency}" style="font-size: 12pt"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column id="slot">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Slot" style="font-size:12pt" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText id="slotdata" value="#{userDtls.occupiedFlag}" style="font-size: 12pt"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The css file is:

```css
table {
   background : Blue ;
}

table.overalltable th {
    background : Yellow;
}

table.overalltable tr {
    background : White;
}

table.overalltable .keydata {
    background : Orange;
}

table.overalltable .occupieddata {
    background : YellowGreen;
}
```

Currently the `.occupieddata` is `YellowGreen`. I would like it to be `Red` when the value is "Occupied". Something like the following:

```
table.overalltable .occupieddata[occupiedFlag='Occupied'] {
    background : Red;
}
```

or like this:

```
table.overalltable .occupieddata[slotdata='Occupied'] {
    background : Red;
}
```

How could I achieve this? I am using the following technologies:

- Java 1.6.0_22-b03
- JSF 1.2
- JSTL 1.2
- Eclipse 3.6.0 (Helios)
- Tomcat 6.0.28 (needs to run also on Weblogic)
- IE 7.0.5730.13
- Firefox: 3.6.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't going to work. Your `<h:outputText>` renders a HTML `<span>` element because you specified the `id` and `style` attributes on it. If you checked the generated HTML code, it should look like this

```xml
<td class="occupieddata"><span id="slotdata" style="font-size: 12pt">Occupied</span></td>
```

Now, you could just add another style class to this as follows:

```xml
<h:outputText id="slotdata" value="#{userDtls.occupiedFlag}"
    style="font-size: 12pt" styleClass="#{userDtls.occupiedFlag}" />
```

so that it ends up like:

```xml
<td class="occupieddata"><span id="slotdata" style="font-size: 12pt" class="Occupied">Occupied</span></td>
```

You could then style it red as follows:

```css
table.overalltable .occupieddata .Occupied {
    background : Red;
}
```

*By the way, consider moving all that `style="font-size:12pt` out the markup into the stylesheet, there where it belongs.*

Comment: There may be a bit of CSS hackery required to get the _span_ to fill the cell (I'd try adding `display: table` to the _span_ and setting `padding: 0px;` on the _td_ elements.) That may not work on all browsers.

Comment: I think you mean `styleClass="#{userDtls.occupiedFlag ? 'Occupied' : ''}"` on the _outputText_.

Comment: @McDowell: regarding the padding, you're right. Just `padding: 0` on `td` and `display: block` on the span should do it. As to the `styleClass`, no I think it doesn't return a `boolean` despite of having "Flag" in the property name. It's also been used as outputtext value.